# DotNetNuke setup issues

Tags: windows-server-2003, .net, internet-explorer

I'm not sure if this will be the right place to ask, however the DNN forums are not working for me at the moment and I have an unhappy client.

I set up DNN 5.2 on a Windows Server 2003 box. I installed SQL Server Express 2008 and then installed DNN. I went through the setup wizard and set up the user accounts, etc. I did a test login using the admin account in Firefox and everything checked out. The next day I get an email from the administrator over there saying he can't log in. Sure enough, when I use Internet Explorer (6, 7 or 8), the login attempt is marked as successful in the DNN event log, but the page still shows as if no one were logged in. Since it's IE-only, I'm really at a loss here and grasping at straws for answers. I see other people having the issue as well, but there's never a reason or solution posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was very simple in retrospect: The test server I was installing DNN on had an underscore in the host name. Apparently this is "illegal" as far as hostnames go and was screwing up the URL rewriting engine in DNN. Removing the underscore from the hostname and reimaging the server fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

One problem we had like this was when we moved servers around.  Here is what we did with most people it was as easy as clear the browser cache - if that works great if not go into the place where the cookies are stored and actually delete all the cookies - dnn uses an authentication cookie and sometimes it can get 'stuck'.

I go months between this hapening myself but everyonce in a while it does happen to me or one of my clients.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Make sure IE is accepting cookies for whatever zone the site is in for the user.  That's the most frequent reason that one browser will not show up as authenticated over another browser.

Comment: I have gone into as many settings as I could and made them all either as permissive as possible, or at least set them to "prompt" in an effort to see if it was a particular setting that was doing it. So far, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a caching issue?  If you navigate to a different page or do a force refresh of the current page (Shift + F5) does it still show as not logged in?